# changing the react state on a stateless component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

hej guys!

I am here trying to do something with the hooks and not sure how to achieve it. This is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form'
import {useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { Login, Logout } from '../../store/actions/Auth'
import '../layout/modalBanG.css'

function LogIn({showHide}){

    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    console.log(showHide)


    const {register, handleSubmit} = useForm()
    const onSubmit = (credentials) => {
        !credentials ? (
        dispatch(Login(credentials))) :
        dispatch(Logout())
    }
    return (
            <>
            <div className={showHide} >
               <div className="card modal-secondary p-3">
                   <button className="btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right p-3" onClick={()=> setShowHide('display-none')}><b>X</b></button>
                   AA
               </div>
            </div>




        </>
        )
    }

export default LogIn
```

Basically on the parent component I have the hook 
`const [showHide, setShowHide] = useState('display-none')`

**edit** parent component beginning

```
function Nav (){

    const [x, setX] = useState('topnav');
    const [showHide, setShowHide] = useState('display-none')

    return(
        <div className="ml-md-5 ml-2 mr-sm-5 mr-2">
        <div className="row" style={{alignItems: 'center', width: '100%'}}>
            <div className="col-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3  pl-sm-5 pr-sm-5 pl-2 pr-2">
                <Link to="/"><img src={logo} alt="logo" id="logo" /></Link>
            </div>

            <div className="col-md-5 d-none d-md-block " >
                <input 
                    // className="fields form-control" 
                    type="text"  
                    placeholder="sök"/>
            </div>

                <div className="col-6 col-md-4 d-none d-lg-block rounded float-right  pl-sm-5 pr-sm-5 pl-2 pr-2">
                    <p onClick={() =>setShowHide('display-block') } > <img src={user} alt="" id=""/> <small> logga in</small></p>
                    <a href="aa" className="icon rounded float-right p-2 text-sm" ><img src={bag} alt="bag" id="bag"/>  <small> varukorg</small></a> 
                </div> 
 <div className="col-6 col-md-4 d-none d-sm-block d-lg-none rounded float-right justify-content-end  pl-sm-5 pr-sm-5 pl-2 pr-2">
                    <a href="aa" className="icon rounded float-right p-2"><small><img src={user} alt="" id=""/> </small>  </a>
                    <a href="aa" className="icon rounded float-right p-2" ><small> <img src={bag} alt="bag" id="bag"/></small> </a> 
                </div>
            <Login showHide={showHide}/>
```

These are the two components in question. I thought about  passing the function as well but followed fb tutorial and did not get anywhere.

That is why kinda came here asking help since you guys are the very good source of knowledge existent in the world!

Comment: You mean, [passing a function through a component's props](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html)?

Comment: @EmileBergeron tried it, does render, but then it is unidentified

Comment: the problem is being a hook I think.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the function by props too.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form'
import {useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { Login, Logout } from '../../store/actions/Auth'
import '../layout/modalBanG.css'

function LogIn({showHide, setShowHide}){

    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    console.log(showHide)


    const {register, handleSubmit} = useForm()
    const onSubmit = (credentials) => {
        !credentials ? (
        dispatch(Login(credentials))) :
        dispatch(Logout())
    }
    return (
            <>
            <div className={showHide} >
               <div className="card modal-secondary p-3">
                   <button className="btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right p-3" onClick={()=> setShowHide('display-none')}><b>X</b></button>
                   AA
               </div>
            </div>




        </>
        )
    }

export default LogIn
```

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, you don't have to pass 'display-none' through as an argument in the setShowHide() function in the child component since that's already defined as the default value in the useState() hook in the parent component. Also, you're not passing any of your parent component logic down as props from what I'm gathering from the code above. The only props you're utilizing are className and onClick that are prebuilt into the button element in JSX/HTML. If you can provide the parent component, I may be able to assist you further in solving this issue. PS - you're not utilizing the useState React hook anywhere in the child component you provided.

Comment: I updated it now with the code that matters from the parent component